# High Side NPN transistor load switching

Tags: transistors, npn

[image]

I have one circuit ( Circuit A) , transistor used is BCP56-16T1G, R1 is fix load of 500 ohm. I am measuring output at VF1 , that comes to around 19 V, I simulate the same circuit , i found the Vf1 is actually come 19 V in simulation too.

And as per calculation too it should be come
24= 10K*Ib+Vbe+R1*(Ic+Ib)
24= 10K*Ib+ 0.7+500*(100*Ib+Ib)   ( since Ic=Hfe*Ib)
so finally Ib=385uA
so Ic= 100*385 = 38.5mA
Drop across R1 = (38.5+0.385)*500 ohm =19.442 Volt.

problem is I need VF1 to be near 24V. off course it will go above 23.3V. but i am getting only 19.4V, and r1 is fixed , so only thing i can change is base resistor. Transistor data sheet does not give max base current limit. but they give max collect current. so i can see max base current will be = 1A/Hfe= 1000mA/100= 10mA. So i try to reduce the base resistor to 10ohm , and I got VF1 near to 23.2V( which I desire circuit B).

So will this Ok to reduce base resistor to this much lower value , is it safe for transistor also.

Comment: That is not a low side switch. A low side switch is when the switch is on the "low side" of the load.

Comment: The actual resistor value doesn't matter, only the current through the base. 500uA is completely fine,  but obviously as photon points out this is a high side switch, not a low side.

Comment: Put R1 between the collector and the ammeter. Tie the emitter to ground and you have a low side switch as Photon says. At present you have an emitter-follower

Comment: Corrected it to high side,

Comment: In this case, you can replace the base resistor with a short. Why? What you have shown is nothing more than a voltage follower. Hence the emitter current is \$ I_E = I_B+I_C = I_B + \beta*I_C = (\beta +1)*I_B \$, so as long as you have a emitter resistor the base current will be \$I_B = \frac{I_E}{\beta+1}\$ and \$I_E = \frac{Vin - V_{BE}}{R_E}\$

Comment: Also, notice the in this circuit we have a quite large voltage drop across the transistor. Vce = Vcc - (Vin - Vbe) and P = Vce*Ie. This is why in most of the time we don't connect the load into the emitter. Instead, we are using the collector as a "output" and PNP transistor for high side switch.

Comment: Are you just trying to understand the circuit? (But you seem to, already.) Or are you trying to switch \$24\:\textrm{V}\$ to your \$500\:\Omega\$ load? If you need a switch, what's your control signal actually look like? (I can't tell if you want to use a \$24\:\textrm{V}\$ control signal, or would prefer different signalling.) And why didn't you consider a PNP switch? I guess I admit I'm confused about the goals here. Is it more theoretical or practical?

Comment: Circuit A was a designed running PCB, 500 ohm R1 is Relay Coil Resistor, do not wan to spin the PCB revision, goal is increase output voltage near to 23V. (since max 23.3 van be achieve)

Comment: @ShortCircuit Just dump \$R_2\$. (Bypass it with a short.) The base will be set as high as possible and the emitter will follow. Your measurements show that \$\beta\approx 120\$. Which is fine. Just use it as an emitter follower and be done with it.

Comment: I think B will be approx 100 as per measurement, since B=Ic/Ib=38.43mA/384.26uA=100.01.

Answer (score 1):

You can take out the resistor completely and leave a short.  As you have already pointed out, the emitter voltage is ~23.3 (one diode drop down), so the emitter current is 23.3/500 or 46.6 ma.  Base current will be 46.6 ma/Hfe.  This would be an "emitter follower" rather than a low-side switch.

Comment: Direct short 24V to base , couldn't damage the transistor ? Since datasheet say max Vbe is 5V only.

Comment: The emitter voltage will rise to stay with the base.

Comment: Wondering why to use  high side switch with NPN( as i used) , since only advantage i can see it that output signal will be in phase with input. where is Low side NPN switch (popularly used) , where we can get full voltage but out of phase with respect to input.